# Why does the Firebase API call for projects.databases.get return an error 404 - Project does not exist, for a project that does exist?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-apis-explorer

I'm new to all of this so I probably missed something really obvious.
When trying to run a simple test using the following API call :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases/get

the response that I get back is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Project 'some-projectname' does not exist.",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}
```

But the project does exist (though the name actually used isn't what is shown here I removed that for privacy reasons). But none the less the actual project is visible in both the Google Cloud Platform UI and the Firebase UI.

To try and add more color and hopefully supply as much detail as possible.
I use the following format for the parameter:
`projects/some-projectname/databases/some-databasename`

and for Credentials, leave both boxes checked: "Google OAuth 2.0" and "API key".

The project is under the Blaze plan and was set up with Firestore in Native Mode.

Please let me know if there is any more detail I can supply or something I should try and thanks kindly for your time.

Comment: It's hard to say much without seeing the actual string you used, but this name worked for me: `projects/project-8080059325282098184/databases/(default)` in the API explorer.

Comment: Cheers, Frank, use of "(default)" instead of the literal database name worked. Any chance you could point me where in the documentation this is, so I can see what else I may have missed reading up on?

Comment: Honestly, I opened the same project in the Firebase console and then looked in the network tab of my browser to check the requests for the database name. Jim definitely had a leg up on me here. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use (default) as the database name as that's the name of the only database that is currently allowed for each project.

I.e. `projects/PROJECT_NAME/databases/(default)`

Comment: That did work! You absolute star, Thank you! Could I ask where in the documentation I overlooked this, please?

Comment: The easiest to read is probably at https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rpc/google.firestore.admin.v1#google.firestore.admin.v1.Database or https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases .

Comment: The key sentence is "A Cloud Firestore Database. Currently only one database is allowed per cloud project; this database must have a databaseId of '(default)'."